# How to implement google sign in

Tags: android, google-signin

I implemented the google sign in api in my android app. Everything was fine until recently. One of the challenges I had was with client_id which regenerated. The most recent that has opened more errors is that the google sign in wont work in the release.apk that built.

After two days of debugging I decided to create a new demo project to start the process afresh. It won't work as the task return `false` for `task.isSuccessful`.

Perhaps there is something I am missing.

```
const val RC_SIGN_IN = 0
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var observer:StartActivityForResults
    private lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient:GoogleSignInClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        observer = StartActivityForResults(activityResultRegistry)
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        sign_in_button.setOnClickListener{
            signIn()
        }
    }

    private fun signIn() {


        val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent

        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            val task = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)

            task?.isSuccess

            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            Log.i("title", "OKCODE ${Activity.RESULT_OK} RESULTCODE ${resultCode}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question, but I faced a similar issue where signing worked in debug builds and wouldn't work for release builds.

In the Firebase console, if you have Google Sign in enabled you will be prompted to enter the SHA-1 Key of your build. Now, what happened in my case was I got the SHA-1 key for debug keystore and didn't do it for the release key-store.

Try,

> keytool -list -v 
> -alias  -keystore <path-to-production-keystore

and entering it on your Firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

Easily add sign-in to your Android app with [FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)

If you haven't already, add Firebase to your Android project.

Add the dependencies for FirebaseUI to your app-level build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
    // ...

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
}
```

In the Firebase console, open the Authentication section and enable the sign-in methods you want to support. Some sign-in methods require additional information, usually available in the service's developer console.

If you support Google Sign-in and haven't yet specified your app's SHA-1 fingerprint, do so from the Settings page of the Firebase console

```
// Choose authentication providers
val providers = arrayListOf(
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build())

// Create and launch sign-in intent
startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),
        RC_SIGN_IN)
```

When the sign-in flow is complete, you will receive the result in onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            // ...
        } else {
            // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
            // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
            // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```